# Multiple angular project within a single project

Tags: angular, frontend, micro-frontend

My angular project is evolving every day, the files are multiplying, the project size is growing

I want to divide the project into several parts.

I want to develop the logic of microservice

**Example:**

Root project : localhost:4200

One project : localhost:1111

Two project : localhost: 2222

Only the project will work on port 4200. I can turn off other ports at any time

I look forward to your advice, Thanks

Your feedback is very important to me

Comment: Simple answer would be to assign desired port numbers with port option

Comment: You can divide the project into multiple modules without separating them into separate processes listening to different ports. You can then use lazy loading to not make the initial loading too slow. Is there a reason you want them to be running on different ports? It's a very uncommon way to do frontend

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following commands already?

```
 ng new mycompany-ng-youtube-player --create-application=false --style=scss
 cd mycompany-ng-youtube-player
 ng generate library @mycompany/ng-youtube-player
 ng generate application ng-youtube-player-demo --routing --style=scss --strict
```

For existing projects you should be able to simply use

```
ng generate library @mycompany/ng-youtube-player
```

In the folder containing the `angular.json`

[Here is an example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-youtube-player/blob/master/projects/mintplayer/ng-youtube-player/src/public-api.ts) of one of my libraries with a test project. You have to correct the root `tsconfig.json` to [specify the path mappings of your libraries](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-youtube-player/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L7) after running the commands:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@mycompany/ng-youtube-player": [
        "projects/mycompany/ng-youtube-player/src/public-api.ts"
      ]
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

Every micro-project i need should be on diffetlrent ports.

I can turn off that port whenever i want

Comment: what was this in response to? This should probably not be an answer